# Give the subcategory a different style to the parent category - NopCommerce

Tags: css, razor, nopcommerce

Good afternoon,
I’m developing a website using NopCommerce 2.65 (in CSHTML) and the customer asked me for two style modifications that I’m unable to do so far:

1st – While the users are browsing a specific subcategory, all of the subcategories in the same level must be colored (red, in this case) except the subcategory that I’m browsing that has the inverted foreground and background colors. I’ve tried changing the CSS3 file, and even after finding these NopCommerce forum topics:
http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/19630/suggestion-categorynavigationcshtml-add-some-style-rules-to-child-categories-so-we-can-easily-customise-through-css.aspx
and 
http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/0c83401329d9
I still haven’t solved it.

2nd – I have the NopTemplate MegaMenu Plugin installed in the site, and while browsing one of the pages associated with the MegaMenu, I want to mark that page as the currently seen placing a small arrow in it.

What is the best option to do so?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, nop 2.65 does not make the distinction between cat and sub cat at display level they use the same view. So no if you are intending to use the admin, thats not possible

The view you are looking for should be 
CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml
or
CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.Mobile.cshtml

The model is the categorymodel

You can either hard code in the view (

if(Model.Id == XXX)
or
if(Model.Name == XXX)

Or you assign a new variable
Adding A New  int Column i.e. (CSSLevel) in the database

***Data SIDE***

**Nop.Core.Domain.Category**
public virtual int CSSLevel{ get; set; }

**Nop.Data.Mapping.CategoryMap**
this.Property(c => c.CSSLevel);

***Admin Side so user can enter himself***

**Nop.Admin.Models.Catalog.CategoryModel**
public int CSSLevel{ get; set; }

**Nop.Admin.Views.Category**
_CreateOrUpdate.cshtml

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CSSLevel)     *Not providing the full table but you should be able to see

And finally to show the web customer

Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.CategoryModel
public int CSSLevel{ get; set; }

Nop.Web.Category.Controller within (category function )
model.CSSLevel = category.CSSLevel;

CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml
   @if (Model.CSSLevel == 1)

Just remember do the models first always and within vs you should see it coming up when u change the views and controller